# How to create a .Net Core MVC Library

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to modularize my .Net Core MVC project into multiple projects. So I have a project A which references project B. Project A is my main project and project B is just like a library which contains some controllers, models and views. Generally it seems to work when I reference project B in project A with `<PackageReference>` in the `*.csproj` file. The controllers are found and executed but the views cannot be found. In project B I've added `<RazorCompileOnBuild>true</RazorCompileOnBuild>` and a `*.View.dll` gets created.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an actual Razor Class Library, not just reference another ASP.NET Core app. Add a new project, and choose ASP.NET Core Web Application. Among the choices on the resulting screen, one will be Razor Class Library. Choose that. Also ensure that the second dropdown at the top is set to ASP.NET Core 2.1 or higher. Move your controllers and views into this new project, and then reference that instead.